# using a SonarQube in android multi-module project

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

[image]
I have a multi-module project with the represented by structure, is it possible to record the result of the sonarqube not in one report (as if it were a monolith), but in different module reports, using one and the same `sonar.login` and one and the same `projectKey`?

I added Sonar Properties to the root of gradle, but they are written in one report (what was to be expected)